# Parse local datastore query takes time on Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have pinned object for first time. Next time i try to fetch same object it takes time sometimes like 5 to 6 second in this the screen turns blank.

Here is my code for pinning. (Both pinning and querying data from local store is done on same table in parse)

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PARSE_IMAGE_TABLE);
List<ParseObject> images = query.find();

for each image i get i do following:

parseObject.pinInBackground(PARSE_PIN_WALLPAPER_INFO,
                            new SaveCallback() {

                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException arg0) {
                                    System.out.println();

                                }
                            });
```

When querying:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(PARSE_IMAGE_TABLE);
        query.whereEqualTo(PARSE_IMAGE_THUMB_URL, imageURL);
        query.fromLocalDatastore();
        query.fromPin();

List<ParseObject> images = query.find(); -- this call takes time
```

Comment: wanted to know is there performance difference between pinning single parse object and list of parse object in background. Because in about code rather than pinning single object at time i pinned list together which made it bit fast... Dont know reason

Comment: Pinning is a serious performance issue at this moment. In my case I'm using `pinAllInBackground` and observing that all queries are getting locked while pinning is in progress in background. It costs about 4-5 seconds on iPhone 5 to wait until the lock release.

Answer (score 1):

Yes their is a lot of performance tweaks you can do in your code.
Pinning a list of objects is faster and better approach.

Instead of using find query use findInBackground.

Also start using pin(String name) and fromPin(String name) instead of fromPin() and fromPin(String name). This has a huge advantage if you have a lot of rows in your parse local storage.